# Slideshow and slider tags

Tags: discussion, tags, review-queues

I recently reviewed two [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6686614) [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6686617) which replaced [slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slider) ([tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slider/info)) with [slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slideshow) ([tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slideshow/info)).

Both were submitted by an user who also [edited other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1731941/vjs?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) in order to perform the same operation.

I'm not sure these edits are relevant because for me a slideshow is something displayed on the full screen or projected on a screen or wall.

I think the descriptions of these tags should be improved (I don't know this subject so I can't help) in order to avoid further ambiguities between these two close tags.

The second edit seems clearly wrong for me, the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27832751/2257664) was about a carousel slider but the question is nos tagged as [slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slideshow). These reviews may be reverted if they are irrelevant.

Comment: `I think the descriptions of these tags should be improved`:  those are some massively plagiarized tag wikis, even one from a 30K+'er.  I know, I need to find a new hobby other than "spot the plagiarized tag wiki".

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables : well done, I didn't see this, these descriptions are just copy-paste from Wikipedia: [Slider (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slider_(computing)) and [Slide_show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_show).

Comment: Yup.  My rule of thumb is, if it looks too good to be true, it's probably copy-and-pasted from somewhere else.  Rule works almost every time, but I'm pleasantly surprised when it doesn't.